# dbeaver mysql connection refused in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04, dbeaver

I am not able to connect to mysql from dbeaver in ubuntu 20.04, I am adding the error screenshot.

mysql is ruuning on machine on the below ports

```
mysqld    5846           mysql   22u  IPv4 122911      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:33060 (LISTEN)
mysqld    5846           mysql   24u  IPv4 120996      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

when i try connection on port 3306 i get below error

[image]

when i try connecting on 33060

[image]

Comment: check MySQL bind access .
make sure MySQL running on public IP and also check 3306 (MySQL ) allowed for your IP.

Comment: IP address is correct. Port might be wrong, or MySQL server might not be running at all

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password123#@!';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I was also facing

```
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

running the first query
This is because my password policy was set to `MEDIUM`. If you face same you can check using

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

rest of the configuration i am attaching screenshot for it:

[image]

Comment: then which error are you getting. Please share

Comment: errors thrown is in the question, this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who encounters: "Connection refused", the solution that worked for me was adding the following to the `my.cnf` file on my WSL:

```
`[mysqld]'`enter code here`
`port=3306 # or any other port`
`bind-address=0.0.0.0`
```

After restarting the MySQL service I was able to connect.